# Normalize given names from various sources

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I retrieve (and receive) bibliography sources from many locations. As such, they're not always set using the same standard. Specifically, when it comes to *given names*, there's a lot of variation. For example, these all represent the same person:

- Arthur Noland Author
- Arthur N. Author
- A. N. Author
- A.N. Author

[`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) manages to consider the first three as the same authors, but seems to fail with the final author (for some reason, `A.N.` - without spaces -  is considered a single given name, compared to `A. N.` - with spaces). Assuming that these are all "A. N. Author", how can I make `biblatex` see that for all these entries?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend      = biber,
  style        = numeric,
  sorting      = nyt,
  giveninits   = true
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{articleA,
  author = {Arthur Noland Author},
  title  = {Article title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year = {2000},
  pages = {1-10}
}
@article{articleB,
  author = {Arthur N. Author},
  title  = {Another article title},
  journal = {Some New Journal},
  year = {2001},
  pages = {11-20}
}
@article{articleC,
  author = {A. N. Author},
  title  = {Yet another article title},
  journal = {Some Fancy Journal},
  year = {2002},
  pages = {21-30}
}
@article{articleD,
  author = {A.N. Author},
  title  = {Completely different article title},
  journal = {Really FaNCy Journal},
  year = {2003},
  pages = {31-40}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

A consequence of the differing given name formats, this affects the sorting as well. With `giveninits = true`, how can one force the sorting to also be done using this, and not the original given names?

Comment: It's not quite correct to say that `biblatex` considers the first three to be the same author. If you look at the name-hashes in the `.bbl`, you'll see they are different. It's just that with your settings (`giveninits=true,`) `biblatex` outputs those three different names in the same way.

Comment: Since both BibTeX and Biber think `A.N.` without the space is not a sequence of name initials, but instead a single name (whose single initial is `A.`), I can't really see a `biblatex`-side solution to this problem. The input is just plain wrong. One could try to use Biber sourcemaps to fix this, but such a regex might wrongly pick up legitimate uses of "A.N." - especially because you can't really do brace grouping in RegExp. The best solution is to fix this on the input side.

Comment: @moewe: That's alright as well; inappropriate input that requires fixing is also a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Biber and BibTeX parse `A.N.` as a single-word (given) name. This means that when name initials are generated we get just "A.". As such I would argue that `A.N. Author` is simply wrong input in this case. It should be `A. N. Author`.

There is pretty much no good way to deal with this on the `biblatex`/LaTeX side of things, since the backend has already done its name parsing and we are left with the incorrect interpretation of the name. One could try to fix this with a Biber sourcemap on the fly, but since RegExp cannot track brace levels, there is a risk of messing with legitimate uses of unspaced initials. Additionally, the RegExp does not account for macro-escapes and similar constructions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend      = biber,
  style        = numeric,
  sorting      = nyt,
  giveninits   = true
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach=setnames]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}, 
        match=\regexp{([[:upper:]]+)\.([[:upper:]]+)\.},
        replace={$1. $2.}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleA,
  author  = {Arthur Noland Author},
  title   = {Article title},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2000},
  pages   = {1-10},
}
@article{articleB,
  author  = {Arthur N. Author},
  title   = {Another article title},
  journal = {Some New Journal},
  year    = {2001},
  pages   = {11-20},
}
@article{articleC,
  author  = {A. N. Author},
  title   = {Yet another article title},
  journal = {Some Fancy Journal},
  year    = {2002},
  pages   = {21-30},
}
@article{articleD,
  author  = {A.N. Author},
  title   = {Completely different article title},
  journal = {Really FaNCy Journal},
  year    = {2003},
  pages   = {31-40},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I think the best solution here is to fix this on the input side and give `A.N. Author` as

```
 A. N. Author
```

---

Not entirely the point of the question, but it's not quite correct to say that biblatex considers the first three forms shown in the question to be the same author. If you look at the name-hashes in the `.bbl`, you'll see they are different. It's just that with your settings (`giveninits=true,`) `biblatex` outputs those three different names in the same way.

BibTeX and `biblatex` make a lot of things easier, but they haven't yet found or established a way to deal with the fact that the same author may have their name given in various forms in publications. You still have to strike a balance between giving the name exactly as it appears in the source and "normalising" the name of the same person into one format across your database.